# How to use gestures with Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using pan and swipe gestures in Ionic 3 (Angular & Typescript) to trigger actions. For now I'm using it like this:

***.html :**

```
<button ion-button block (panleft)="actionForLeftPan()"  (panright)="actionForRightPan()">Touch me</button>
```

***.ts:**

```
actionForLeftPan(): void
{
    // Some actions
}

actionForRightPan(): void
{
    // Some other actions
}
```

It works but in some cases it needs a lot of functions calls in html file. Is there a way to do something for example something like this:

***.html:**

```
<button ion-button block (pan)="actionForPan(event)">Touch me</button>
```

***.ts:**

```
actionForPan(event): void
{
    if ( event.left )
    {
        // Do some actions
    }

    if ( event.right )
    {
        // Do other actions
    }
}
```

This would simplify a lot code readability and maintenance.

Comment: All you have to do is pass in $event when calling (pan)="actionForPan($event)". You should console.log(event) in actionForPan() to see it's result.

Comment: Thank you JoeriShoeby, it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ll you have to do is pass in $event when calling (pan)="actionForPan($event)". You should console.log(event) in actionForPan() to see it's result.

More info could be found at: [GestureController Source Code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/gestures/gesture-controller.ts#L34)